# Find the interval of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having trouble finding the interval of convergence of the series

$$\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1-x^n} $$

I tried to use the ratio test but it does not work because I keep having an x in the sum.
I would appreciate it if someone gave me a clue about where to start!

Comment: Having an $x$ in the result of the ratio test is not an issue. In particular, we want to solve for the values of $x$ such that the ratio is less than $1$.

Comment: @qianqian07 the thing is that using the ratio test I get to simplify all $x$ and get that my answer = 1, which does not work.

Comment: @qianqian07 Nevermind, I got that the series converges for all $x$, is this correct?

Comment: The ratio should evaluate to $\left|\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n-1}}\right|=\left|\frac{x-1}{1-x^{n+1}}+1\right|$, which does not simplify to $1$. This ratio should lead to a finite interval of convergence.

Comment: The answer is $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Raabe's test with $$a_n=\vert \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}\vert$$Computation of $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)$$ shows that if $\vert x \vert<1$ the limit is $\infty$ and the series converges; if $\vert x \vert >0$ the limit is 0 and the series diverges.